# Root Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo Plus running Android 4.4.4 without losing data

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-3-neo

I want to know how to root my Android (Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo Plus, 4.4.4) without touching a single one of my files.

Answer (score 0):

Do not install kingo root. Its an exploit not true root and a pain in the butt to get rid of,  the following after much looking did it. Should it be too late, install supersu over the top of it then remove supersu through settings to unroot should you want to re-sell.A better way is to search on XDA for the latest clockworkmod recovery or TWRP for your device and use Odin to flash the recovery boot.img. Then holding "vol up" and "home" press the power button and it should boot into recovery. From there you can perform a complete backup, flash roms or root by installing zips. This process only writes to the boot not any other part unless you flash a ROM, then the phone is wiped. Make sure you get the right files for your device....More Here
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2793285

Answer (score 0):

Use KingRoot, easy root and unroot. Installing a custom recovery wouldn't be a good choice if you have a device with warranty and also if you're getting to know "TWRP Recovery" " Odin" "recovery" "Flash" for the first time.

Comment: Well, I'm going the Kingo method.

Comment: Or not as that didn't work. I'm using the below method.